# Git failed with a fatal error.Could not read from remote repository.Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

I just got a new laptop.

On old laptop, I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 version 15.9.43.
On new laptop, I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 version 15.9.44.

On Git, I cloned the TFS repository using SSH.

On old laptop, I am able to clone or pull/push codes in Visual Studio, so that means my user name does have the access to the repository, and the repository exists.

On new laptop, I am able to clone the repository using Git Bash.
But, when trying to do that in Visual Studio, I am getting an error

```
"Git failed with a fatal error.
 Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists. "
```

[image]

On both old and new laptop, the Visual Studio Git Settings are the same, ie Cryptographic network provider on both laptops are set to OpenSSL.

On new laptop I have created SSH key added the SSH Public keys to TFS Git.

How can I fix this error ?

Thank you